# session.queryObjects does not support secondary types

Tags: cmis, opencmis

Reading this https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/properties/index.html#retrieving-properties, I thought it would be possible to retrieve secondary types using queryObjects method, but it does not. For example, I'm trying to get `cm:author` from Alfresco, it returns null. Here is my piece of code:

```
OperationContext oc = OperationContextUtils.createMaximumOperationContext();
ItemIterable<CmisObject> results = session.queryObjects(task.getCmisType(), where, false, oc);

...

Object value = cmisObject.getPropertyValue("cm:author");
```

Am I missing something?

P.S: I'm using Chemistry 1.0.0, CMIS 1.1, Binding: Browser

**UPDATE:**

Okay I found something interesting, In order to retrieve `cm:author`, I have to reload the cmisObject to make it work:

```
results = session.queryObjects("cmis:document", "IN_FOLDER('" + folder.getId() + "')", false, oc);
results.each { it -> 
    object = session.getObject(it.getId()); 
    author = object.getPropertyValue("cm:author"); 

    if(author != null) { 
        println object.getId() + " => " + author; 
    }
```

Bug?

Comment: Did you try using the Chemistry Workbench to see exactly what properties you're getting back, and what prefixes are applied to them?

Comment: Hopefully [@florian-müller](http://stackoverflow.com/users/345826/florian-m%c3%bcller) will be along in a bit to advise!

Comment: Repository vendor, version and service URL, please.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure cm:author is what you want. That is not the person who created the document node in Alfresco. That is an editable property that anyone can set to anything, and by default it is null.

If what you want is the actual username of the person who created the document node, you should use cmis:createdBy which is mapped to alfresco's cm:creator property.

Assuming cm:author is definitely what you want, you have two choices regarding how to get it. First, you can get it from the object. But in order to get it from the object you must first fetch the object. Your query returns QueryResult objects, not CmisObjects.

So you should do something like:

```
ItemIterable<QueryResult> results = session.query(queryString, false);
for (QueryResult qResult : results) {
    String objectId = "";
    PropertyData<?> propData = qResult.getPropertyById("cmis:objectId"); 
    if (propData != null) {
        objectId = (String) propData.getFirstValue();
    }
    CmisObject obj = session.getObject(session.createObjectId(objectId));
    // Dump the object here
    System.out.println("Author: " + obj.getPropertyValue("cm:author");
}
```

Your second option would be to get the property value from the query result. Your ability to do this depends on the query you ran. The author property is defined on an aspect, so you must do a join in order to get it back. The query might look something like:

```
queryString = "select content.cmis:name, content.cmis:objectId, author.cm:author from cmis:document content JOIN cm:author author ON content.cmis:objectId = author.cmis:objectId WHERE content.cmis:objectId is not null AND author.cm:author = 'Jeff'";
```

If you use that query, then you can grab the author using the QueryResult, like this:

```
System.out.println("Author: " + qResult.getPropertyValueByQueryName("author.cm:author"));
```

Hopefully that explains the difference between fetching the value from a query result and fetching a property value from the object itself.

Comment: Thanks Jeff,

1/ Here is the URL: https://cmis.alfresco.com/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser, the rest is already indicated

2/ I'm using `queryObjects()` method, the results is a set of `CmisObject`. See https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/queries/index.html

So, once again, how come I have to "reload" the same object by doing this `object = session.getObject(it.getId());`?

Comment: Being said, looks like `query()` method offers more possibilities, it actually support JOIN, so you can make your select more restrictive. For example: `SELECT * FROM cmis:document D JOIN cm:author P ON P.cmis:objectId = D.cmis:objectId WHERE IN_FOLDER(D, '5be4b981-c2a7-48cf-8b89-a5bb99bc0f05') AND P.cm:author IS NOT NULL` I don't think it is possible to do the same using `queryObjects()`, except doing a post treatment in Java

Comment: No idea then, regarding the problem? :/

Comment: Just like you cannot get the author without a join if you were to do your own query (something like select * from cmis:document), you cannot get aspect-defined properties via queryObjects because it also does not do a join.

Comment: Yes indeed... But regarding the orginal problem of this post, don't you see a problem here?

Comment: No, I think Alfresco would tell you it is working as designed, and I think Apache Chemistry would tell you to talk to Alfresco. But feel free to send the question to the Apache Chemistry listserv and see what the other devs think.